# Selenium Python send_keys to a code block

Tags: python, selenium

I have to insert some python code into a code block.[image: This is the code block.]

I tried to fetch the block and click on it. That works!

```
code_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="prog-div-py3"]/div/div[6]')
code_box.click()
```

But, when I tried to send_keys to it, got some errors.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element 
not interactable
```

Sample python code:

```
def hello:
   print("Hi")
```

Manually, when I added the above code into that code block, the structure looks like this.[image: DOM structure]

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Webelement here is CodeMirror. The following code worked for me, pls try using it:

```
WebElement codeMirror = driver.findElement(By.className("CodeMirror"));
WebElement codeLine = codeMirror.findElements(By.className("CodeMirror-line")).get(0);
codeLine.click();
WebElement txtbx = codeMirror.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea"));
txtbx.sendKeys(text);
```